# Replace Greek letters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I've got the function below which replaces greek letters with a similar 'normal' letter. However, a few browsers don't really like this code (IE). I imagine its because of the greek letters in the code.

How can I do this without breaking js?

```
function string_to_url(string) {
    replace = new Array('á','Á','é','É','í','Í','ó','Ó','ú','Ú','ü','Ü','ö','Ö','õ','Õ','û','Û','¾','š','è','ž','ý','ô','ä','ò','å','¼','Š','È','Ž','Ý','Ò','Å','ì','Ì','ê','Æ','æ','Ø','ø');

    replace_n = new Array('a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O', 'u','U','u','U','o','O','o','O','u','U','l','s','c','z','y','o','a','n','a','l','s','C','Z','Y','N','A','e','E','e','AE', 'ae','O','o');

    for (var i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
        string = string.replace(replace[i], replace_n[i]);
    }




    return string;
}
```

Comment: any chance of a jsfiddle?

Comment: what is the problem? Errors? Console messages?

Comment: those are not greek letters.. two reasons: you're confused about greek letters or your edit process of copy/paste has altered your intention.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings

Comment: I just tried in IE9 with <input type="button" onclick="alert(string_to_url('testing some weird é cháráctÉrŠ'))" /> and didn't get any errors

Comment: Also you can use encodeURIComponent instead of doing stuff manually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9667752/295783

Comment: @PA. Sometimes `ελληνική` looks like `ÉšèžÓúü` for some people.

Comment: I needed the same thing a couple of years ago... I recently found a solution with `String.prototype.normalize()`. Question and answer can be found here: [Javascript - normalize accented greek characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797754/1561148)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to unicode encode the non-standard chars in your JS see if that works better with a "pure-ASCII" source:

```
function string_to_url(string) {
    var replace = new Array('\u00E1','\u00C1','\u00E9','\u00C9','\u00ED','\u00CD','\u00F3','\u00D3','\u00FA','\u00DA','\u00FC','\u00DC','\u00F6','\u00D6','\u00F5','\u00D5','\u00FB','\u00DB','\u00BE','\u0161','\u00E8','\u017E','\u00FD','\u00F4','\u00E4','\u00F2','\u00E5','\u00BC','\u0160','\u00C8','\u017D','\u00DD','\u00D2','\u00C5','\u00EC','\u00CC','\u00EA','\u00C6','\u00E6','\u00D8','\u00F8');
    var replace_n = new Array('a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O', 'u','U','u','U','o','O','o','O','u','U','l','s','c','z','y','o','a','n','a','l','s','C','Z','Y','N','A','e','E','e','AE', 'ae','O','o');

    for (var i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
        string = string.replace(replace[i], replace_n[i]);
    }

    return string;
}
```

(I did the conversion with http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/).