# Javascript - normalize accented greek characters

Tags: javascript, regex, character, normalization

I am trying to apply some kind of normalization to greek text (use lower case, remove accents and replace ς with σ). For example I would like "ἀντίθεσις" (greek polytonic) and "αντίθεσις" (modern greek) become "αντιθεσισ".
I ran through [unicode-table.com](http://unicode-table.com) and wrote down which character replacements I should do.

```
Greek and Coptic (Range: 0370— 03FF) 
ΆΑά -> α
ΈΕέ -> ε
ΉΗή -> η
ΊΪΙίΐ -> ι
ΌΟό -> ο
ΎΫΥΰϋύ -> υ
ΏΩώ -> ω

Greek Extended (Range: 1F00— 1FFF)
ἀἁἂἃἄἅἆἇὰάᾀᾁᾂᾃᾄᾅᾆᾇᾰᾱᾲᾳᾴᾶᾷἈἉἊἋἌἍἎἏᾈᾉᾊᾋᾌᾍᾎᾏᾸᾹᾺΆᾼ -> α
ἐἑἒἓἔἕὲέἘἙἚἛἜἝῈΈ -> ε
ἠἡἢἣἤἥἦἧὴήᾐᾑᾒᾓᾔᾕᾖᾗῂῃῄῆῇἨἩἪἫἬἭἮἯᾘᾙᾚᾛᾜᾝᾞᾟῊΉῌ -> η
ἰἱἲἳἴἵἶἷὶίῐῑῒΐῖῗἸἹἺἻἼἽἾἿῘῙῚΊ -> ι
ὀὁὂὃὄὅὸόὈὉὊὋὌὍῸΌ -> ο
ὐὑὒὓὔὕὖὗὺύῠῡῢΰῦῧὙὛὝὟῨῩῪΎ -> υ
ὠὡὢὣὤὥὦὧὼώᾠᾡᾢᾣᾤᾥᾦᾧῲῳῴῶῷὨὩὪὫὬὭὮὯᾨᾩᾪᾫᾬᾭᾮᾯῺΏῼ -> ω
ῤῥῬ -> ρ
```

I am wondering if there is a smart way to do these replacements and avoid checking strings character by character.

#### 1st try (thanks [@Tyblitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938203/tyblitz))

```js
normal = 'Αντίθετα με αυτό που θεωρεί η πλειοψηφία, το Lorem Ipsum δεν είναι απλά ένα τυχαίο κείμενο. Οι ρίζες του βρίσκονται σε ένα κείμενο Λατινικής λογοτεχνίας του 45 π.Χ., φτάνοντας την ηλικία του πάνω από 2000 έτη.';

pol = 'Μήγαρις ἔχω ἄλλο στὸ νοῦ μου πάρεξ ἐλευθερία καὶ γλώσσα;';

console.log(normalizeGreek(normal));
console.log(normalizePolytonicGreek(pol));

function normalizeGreek(text) {
    text = text.replace(/Ά|Α|ά/g, 'α')
        .replace(/Έ|Ε|έ/g, 'ε')
        .replace(/Ή|Η|ή/g, 'η')
        .replace(/Ί|Ϊ|Ι|ί|ΐ|ϊ/g, 'ι')
        .replace(/Ό|Ο|ό/g, 'ο')
        .replace(/Ύ|Ϋ|Υ|ύ|ΰ|ϋ/g, 'υ')
        .replace(/Ώ|Ω|ώ/g, 'ω')
        .replace(/Σ|ς/g, 'σ');
    return text;
}


function normalizePolytonicGreek(text) {
    text = text.replace(/Ά|Α|ά|ἀ|ἁ|ἂ|ἃ|ἄ|ἅ|ἆ|ἇ|ὰ|ά|ᾀ|ᾁ|ᾂ|ᾃ|ᾄ|ᾅ|ᾆ|ᾇ|ᾰ|ᾱ|ᾲ|ᾳ|ᾴ|ᾶ|ᾷ|Ἀ|Ἁ|Ἂ|Ἃ|Ἄ|Ἅ|Ἆ|Ἇ|ᾈ|ᾉ|ᾊ|ᾋ|ᾌ|ᾍ|ᾎ|ᾏ|Ᾰ|Ᾱ|Ὰ|Ά|ᾼ/g, 'α')
        .replace(/Έ|Ε|έ|ἐ|ἑ|ἒ|ἓ|ἔ|ἕ|ὲ|έ|Ἐ|Ἑ|Ἒ|Ἓ|Ἔ|Ἕ|Ὲ|Έ/g, 'ε')
        .replace(/Ή|Η|ή|ἠ|ἡ|ἢ|ἣ|ἤ|ἥ|ἦ|ἧ|ὴ|ή|ᾐ|ᾑ|ᾒ|ᾓ|ᾔ|ᾕ|ᾖ|ᾗ|ῂ|ῃ|ῄ|ῆ|ῇ|Ἠ|Ἡ|Ἢ|Ἣ|Ἤ|Ἥ|Ἦ|Ἧ|ᾘ|ᾙ|ᾚ|ᾛ|ᾜ|ᾝ|ᾞ|ᾟ|Ὴ|Ή|ῌ/g, 'η')
        .replace(/Ί|Ϊ|Ι|ί|ΐ|ἰ|ἱ|ἲ|ἳ|ἴ|ἵ|ἶ|ἷ|ὶ|ί|ῐ|ῑ|ῒ|ΐ|ῖ|ῗ|Ἰ|Ἱ|Ἲ|Ἳ|Ἴ|Ἵ|Ἶ|Ἷ|Ῐ|Ῑ|Ὶ|Ί/g, 'ι')
        .replace(/Ό|Ο|ό|ὀ|ὁ|ὂ|ὃ|ὄ|ὅ|ὸ|ό|Ὀ|Ὁ|Ὂ|Ὃ|Ὄ|Ὅ|Ὸ|Ό/g, 'ο')
        .replace(/Ύ|Ϋ|Υ|ΰ|ϋ|ύ|ὐ|ὑ|ὒ|ὓ|ὔ|ὕ|ὖ|ὗ|ὺ|ύ|ῠ|ῡ|ῢ|ΰ|ῦ|ῧ|Ὑ|Ὓ|Ὕ|Ὗ|Ῠ|Ῡ|Ὺ|Ύ/g, 'υ')
        .replace(/Ώ|Ω|ώ|ὠ|ὡ|ὢ|ὣ|ὤ|ὥ|ὦ|ὧ|ὼ|ώ|ᾠ|ᾡ|ᾢ|ᾣ|ᾤ|ᾥ|ᾦ|ᾧ|ῲ|ῳ|ῴ|ῶ|ῷ|Ὠ|Ὡ|Ὢ|Ὣ|Ὤ|Ὥ|Ὦ|Ὧ|ᾨ|ᾩ|ᾪ|ᾫ|ᾬ|ᾭ|ᾮ|ᾯ|Ὼ|Ώ|ῼ/g, 'ω')
        .replace(/ῤ|ῥ|Ῥ/g, 'ρ')
        .replace(/Σ|ς/g, 'σ');
    return text;
}
```

#### 2nd try:

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797754/1561148) below which makes use of `String.prototype.normalize()` and prevents you from keeping lists with all the greek accented characters from the unicode table.

Comment: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte  thanks for providing me this useful post. I will try to make a 2nd version of my functions following that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in another way than by checking for each letter, but that doesn't make it any worse.

Simply chain your `.replace` functions like so:

```
result = string.replace(/Ά|Α|ά/g,'α')
  .replace(/Έ|Ε|έ/g,'ε')
  .replace(/Ή|Η|ή/g,'η');
// & so on...
```

Or if you rather loop over it, which you presumably do if you have greater amounts of characters to check against,and which is also better for code maintainability, store the character matches in an array of objects/ arrays.
Eg. with an object:

```
var cvtValues =  [ /* from = chars to convert; to = conversion output */
  {from:['Ά','Α','ά'], to: 'α'}
  {from:['Έ','Ε','έ'], to: 'ε'}
  {from:['Ή','Η','ή'], to: 'η'}];
/* loop over all from-to containers */
for ( var i = 0; i < cvtValues.length; i++ ) {
  /* loop over all characters in the 'from' array & replace them with 'to' value*/
  for ( var x = 0; x < cvtValues[i].from.length; x++ ) {
    string = string.replace(new RegExp(cvtValues[i].from[x],'g'), cvtValues[i].to);
    /* You could assign this to another variable, eg. result if you wated */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I have also found the following solution which makes use of: [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

```js
normal = 'Αντίθετα με αυτό που θεωρεί η πλειοψηφία, το Lorem Ipsum δεν είναι απλά ένα τυχαίο κείμενο. Οι ρίζες του βρίσκονται σε ένα κείμενο Λατινικής λογοτεχνίας του 45 π.Χ., φτάνοντας την ηλικία του πάνω από 2000 έτη.';

pol = 'Μήγαρις ἔχω ἄλλο στὸ νοῦ μου πάρεξ ἐλευθερία καὶ γλώσσα;';

console.log(normalizeGreek(normal));
console.log(normalizePolytonicGreek(pol));

function normalizeGreek(text) {
    return text.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}


function normalizePolytonicGreek(text) {
    return text.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}
```

#### How it works + example:

Inside `.normalize('NFD')`, accented characters are decomposed to:

- the character itself
- followed by the equivalent Combining Diacritical Mark (see: [range [0300-036f]](https://unicode-table.com/en/#combining-diacritical-marks))

Removing these marks is easy by using: `.replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")`

```js
a = "ἄ"
console.log(a);             // prints: ἄ
console.log(Array.from(a)); // prints: [ "ἄ" ]

b = a.normalize('NFD')
console.log(b);             // prints: ἄ 
console.log(Array.from(b)); // prints: [ "α", "̓", "́" ]

c = a.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
console.log(c);             // prints: α
console.log(Array.from(c)); // prints: [ "α" ]
```

#### Interesting links:

- [Unicode® Standard Annex #15 - Unicode Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)
- [Normalization charts](http://unicode.org/charts/normalization/)
- [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/1561148)

Comment: Neat solution and very well explained, +1!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the npm library [greek-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/greek-utils) which has methods that perform what you are looking for such as replacement of accented and other diacritics characters.

For modern Greek:

```
var greekUtils = require('greek-utils');

var sanitized = greekUtils.sanitizeDiacritics('Αρνάκι άσπρο και παχύ');
console.log(sanitized); //Αρνακι ασπρο και παχυ
```

and ancient Greek:

```
var greekUtils = require('greek-utils');

var sanitized = greekUtils.sanitizeDiacritics('Ἐξ οὗ καὶ δῆλον ὅτι οὐδεμία τῶν ἠθικῶν ἀρετῶν φύσει ἡμῖν ἐγγίνεται');
console.log(sanitized); //Εξ ου και δηλον οτι ουδεμια των ηθικων αρετων φυσει ημιν εγγινεται
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Vassilis!